# NullPointerException on Snackbar touch or swipe in appcompat-v7:23.0.0

Tags: java, android, material-design, snackbar

I found an error when swiping the Snackbar, like this code https://github.com/nuuneoi/Lab-Android-DesignLibrary .

1.Add this code in proper context to the app with appcompat-v7:23.0.0:

```
Snackbar
  .make(rootLayout, R.string.snackbar_text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
  .show();
```

2.The view must has a Toolbar within AppBarLayout like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

3.Swipe the Snackbar on the phone.

4.App crash

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.onInterceptTouchEvent(AppBarLayout.java:729)
            at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.onInterceptTouchEvent(AppBarLayout.java:629)
            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.performIntercept(CoordinatorLayout.java:357)
            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout.java:409)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1859)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2086)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1533)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, fixed in version 23.0.1. of support library

Answer (score 0):

you have no other view embedded in the coordinatorlayout. Hence, the snackbar doesn't have any other view to coordinate with.

Comment: actually, I have. You may see the code on [link](https://github.com/nuuneoi/Lab-Android-DesignLibrary) . The demo will crash when swipe the Snackbar